# Wiki Syntax for Indentation under Numbered List

Tags: syntax, wiki

I need the wiki syntax for an indented bullet within a numbered list. For example,

I want a wiki page that looks like this:

1. foo

   - baz
   - baz
2. bar
3. boom
4. kaboom

Thank you.

Comment: Which wiki is this for? Different wikis have different syntaxes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can get is

```
# foo
:* baz
:* baz
#<li value="2"> bar
# boom
# kaboom
```

I cant seem to get the numbering to continue where it was automatically. Maybe you'll see something I don't here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:List#Continuing_a_list_item_after_a_sub-item